# What camera did Cindy Sherman shoot with?

Tags: history, photographer

I'm studying photographers and am curious to know what camera CS used for her work. I'm sure the latest is on digital but wanted to know what she started out with.

Comment: The only technical mention I see about here is that her early works were on 35mm B&W film, likely Tri-X. The complete absence of any camera indication on the several sites I checked could be a hint that the camera changed often.

Comment: With film, why does the camera even matter? It's all about the lens and the film.